# Deleting cookies during jmeter test

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have such test structure :

Thread Group1
   Http request Get < Here we get cookies
   Http request Post
   .... 
   Module Controller -> Thread group2 > Simple controller

Thread Group2
   Http request Get < There we should come without cookies to achieve new ones.

How can i delete cookies in Thread Group 1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you will add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to thread group, it will store cookie and use it for all future requests
"Each JMeter thread has its own "cookie storage area". So, if you are 
testing a web site that uses a cookie for storing information for 
particular sessions then each JMeter thread will have its own session""

Answer (score 0):

CookieManager does not share cookies between threads, so I don't see any problem for you here...